# Crear tabla de forma vertical con PHP

Tags: php, html, html-tabla

Estoy empezando con PHP y tengo que hacer un ejercicio de mostrar unos resultados calculados a partir de un array en un tabla. Los datos los obtengo pero a la hora de crear la tabla no doy con la formula de hacerla de forma horizontal.
Me explico, yo consigo hacerla asi:

[image: Mi tabla]

Pero necesito hacerla asi:
[image: Tabla correcto]

Es decir de forma vertical. Despues de muchas vueltas no doy con la solucion.
Pongo el codigo que he usado:

Frecuencias

```
        #verde{

            background: green;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
        }

        table{
          border-collapse:collapse;
          background-color: #97BB00;
          border-color: white;
          text-align: center;

        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table  border="solid" align="center" >
        <?php
        //Vavriables
        $valores = array(7, 19, 25, 12, 23, 15, 8, 16);

        $total = array_sum($valores);


        echo "<tr><td id=\"verde\"><b>X1</b></td>";
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($valores); $i++) {
            $indice = $i + 1;
            echo "<td> <b>$indice</b> </td>";
        }
        echo "<td id=\"verde\"><b>TOTAL<b></td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        echo "<tr><td id=\"verde\"><b>Frecuencia<br> absoluta</b></td>";
        foreach ($valores as $value) {
            echo "<td>$value</td>";
        }
        echo "<td id=\"verde\"><b>$total</b></td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        echo "<tr><td id=\"verde\"><b>Frecuencia<br> absoluta <br>acumulada</b></td>";
        $frecuenciaAbAcumulada = 0;
        foreach ($valores as $value) {
            $frecuenciaAbAcumulada += $value;
            echo "<td>$frecuenciaAbAcumulada</td>";
        }
        echo "<td id=\"verde\"><b>$total</b></td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        echo "<tr><td id=\"verde\"><b>Frecuencia<br>relativa</b></td>";
        $fr = 0;
        $frecuenciaRelativa = 0;
        foreach ($valores as $value) {
            $fr = $value / array_sum($valores);
            $frecuenciaRelativa = round($fr, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
            echo "<td>$frecuenciaRelativa</td>";
        }

        $totalFrecuenciaRelativa = 0;
        foreach ($valores as $value) {
            $totalFrecuenciaRelativa += ($value / array_sum($valores));
        }
        echo "<td id=\"verde\"><b>$totalFrecuenciaRelativa</b></td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        echo "<tr><td id=\"verde\"><b>Frecuencia<br>Relativa<br>acumulada</b></td>";
        $fra = 0;
        $frecuenciaRelativaAcumulada = 0;

        foreach ($valores as $value) {
            $frecuenciaRelativaAcumulada += $value / array_sum($valores);
            $fra = round($frecuenciaRelativaAcumulada, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
            echo "<td>$fra</td>";
        }

        echo "<td id=\"verde\"><b>$fra</b></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        ?>

    </table>

</body>
```

Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te propongo la siguiente solución.

- El código es escrito de una forma ordenada y limpia, sin tantos echo por todas partes. Ayuda para esos fines crear una variable a la cual vamos concatenando todo.
- Ten en cuenta el uso de `number_format` para obtener decimales de dos dígitos después del punto.
- No entendí bien lo que quieres presentar en la última fila (`Total`), supuse que allí querrías una suma vertical de todos los valores de cada celda. Si no es así no será problemático cambiar ese valor.
- No he aplicado estilos directamente en la tabla, no es recomendable. Se recomienda usar nombres de clases y aplicar los estilos mediante CSS. De ese modo tu documento HTML es más independiente y si quieres cambiar cualquier elemento de estilo modificas el CSS sin tener que recorrer todos los HTML. Puedes cambiar los valores a tu gusto en cuanto a colores y otras cosas...

### Código

**<kbd>[VER DEMO](http://rextester.com/OVM38999)</kbd>**

```
<?php 

    /*Declaramos todas nuestras variables fuera del bucle*/
    $valores = array(7, 19, 25, 12, 23, 15, 8, 16);
    $sum_valores=array_sum($valores);

    $frecuenciaAbAcumulada = 0;
    $sum_faa=0;

    $frecuenciaRelativa = 0;
    $sum_fr=0;
    $fr = 0;

    $frecuenciaRelativaAcumulada = 0;
    $sum_fra=0;

    /*Usaremos una variable para ir construyendo la tabla*/

    $tablaHTML="<table>";
    $tablaHTML.="<th>X</th>
                 <th>Frecuencia absoluta</th>
                 <th>Frecuencia absoluta acumulada</th>
                 <th>Frecuencia relativa</th>
                 <th>Frecuencia relativa acumulada</th>";

    /*Leemos las claves y valores del array. Usamos $k+1 para los números*/
    foreach ($valores as $k=>$v) 

    {
        /*Calculamos valores*/
        $contador=$k+1;
        $frecuenciaAbAcumulada += $v;
        $sum_faa+=$frecuenciaAbAcumulada;

        $fr = $v / $sum_valores;
        $frecuenciaRelativa = number_format(round($fr, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP),2);
        $sum_fr+=$fr;

        $frecuenciaRelativaAcumulada += $v / $sum_valores;
        $fra = number_format(round($frecuenciaRelativaAcumulada, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP),2);
        $sum_fra+=$fra;

        /*Agregamos valores a la tabla*/
        $tablaHTML.="<tr>";
        $tablaHTML.="<td>$contador</td>"; 
        $tablaHTML.="<td>$v</td>"; 
        $tablaHTML.="<td>$frecuenciaAbAcumulada</td>"; 
        $tablaHTML.="<td>$frecuenciaRelativa</td>"; 
        $tablaHTML.="<td>$fra</td>";
        $tablaHTML.="</tr>";

   }

    /*La línea de Totales la agregamos fuera del bucle*/
    $tablaHTML.="<tr class=\"total\">";
    $tablaHTML.="<td>Total</td>";
    $tablaHTML.="<td>$sum_valores</td>";
    $tablaHTML.="<td>$sum_faa</td>";
    $tablaHTML.="<td>$sum_fr</td>";
    $tablaHTML.="<td>$sum_fra</td>";
    $tablaHTML.="</tr>";

    $tablaHTML.="</table>";

    /*Imprimimos la tabla*/
    echo $tablaHTML;

?>
```

### Resultado

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th {
  background-color: #089541;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #a0bf8d
}

.total td {
  background-color: #5fff00;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <th>X</th>
  <th>Frecuencia absoluta</th>
  <th>Frecuencia absoluta acumulada</th>
  <th>Frecuencia relativa</th>
  <th>Frecuencia relativa acumulada</th>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>0.06</td>
    <td>0.06</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>0.15</td>
    <td>0.21</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>51</td>
    <td>0.20</td>
    <td>0.41</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>63</td>
    <td>0.10</td>
    <td>0.50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>86</td>
    <td>0.18</td>
    <td>0.69</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>101</td>
    <td>0.12</td>
    <td>0.81</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>109</td>
    <td>0.06</td>
    <td>0.87</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>125</td>
    <td>0.13</td>
    <td>1.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="total">
    <td>Total</td>
    <td>125</td>
    <td>568</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>4.55</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me parece una respuesta excelente. Estoy analizando el codigo y me esta ayudando mucho a comprender este lenguaje. Mil gracias.

Answer (score 0):

falta terminar, pero es algo asi (las 3 primeras columnas):

```
<?php
$valores = array(7, 19, 25, 12, 23, 15, 8, 16);
$total = array_sum($valores);
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>Frecuencia absoluta</td>
        <td>Frecue...acumulada</td>
        <td>freq relativa</td>
        <td>freq relat acumuladda</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $indice = 0;
    $acumulado = 0;
    foreach ($valores as $value) {
        $indice++;
        $acumulado += $value;
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $indice . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $acumulado . "</td>";
        $fr = 0;
        $frecuenciaRelativa = 0;
            $fr = $value / array_sum($valores);
            $frecuenciaRelativa = round($fr, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
            echo "<td>$frecuenciaRelativa</td>";
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando tengas problemas de este tipo te recomiendo que hagas primero la tabla solo con HTML, seguidamente añadas estilos y ya una vez que lo tengas claro veas como construirla con PHP.

El HTML que estás buscando sería éste (versión simplificada):

```css
.green {
 border-collapse:collapse;
 background-color: #97BB00;
}
 .green td,
 .green th,
 .green tr {
  border: 1px solid white;
  text-align: center;
 }
 .green td,
 .green th {
  padding: .2em .8em;
 }
#verde{
 background: green;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<table class="green" align="center">

 <tr>
  <td id="verde"><b>X1</b></td>
  <td id="verde"><b>Frecuencia<br> absoluta</b></td>
  <td id="verde"><b>Frecuencia<br> absoluta <br>acumulada</b></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><b>1</b></td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>7</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><b>2</b></td>
  <td>19</td>
  <td>26</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td id="verde"><b>TOTAL</b></td>
  <td id="verde"><b>125</b></td>
  <td id="verde"><b>125</b></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Hay buenos tutoriales sobre construcción de tablas en:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp y http://www.htmlquick.com/tutorials/tables.html

Y una posible solución:

```
<?php

/**
 * Declaración funciones
 *
 */
    function echoVerde( $str ) {

        echo '<td id="verde"><b>' . $str . '</b></td>';
    }
    function echoValue( $value, $strong=FALSE ) {

        if ( $strong )
            echo '<td><b>' . $value . '</b></td>';

        else
            echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
    }

    function calculaAcumuladas( $valores ) {

        $arr = array();
        $temp = 0;
        foreach ( $valores as $value ) {

            $temp += $value;
            $arr[] = $temp;
        }


        return $arr;
    }
    function calculaFAAs( $valores_fa ) {

        return calculaAcumuladas( $valores_fa );
    }
    function calculaFRs( $valores_fa ) {

        $arr = array();
        $total = array_sum( $valores_fa );

        foreach ( $valores_fa as $key => $fa ) {

            $temp = $fa / $total;
            $arr[] = number_format( round( $temp, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP ), 2 );
        }

        return $arr;
    }
    function calculaFRAs( $valores_fr ) {

        return calculaAcumuladas( $valores_fr );
    }


/**
 * Declaración variables
 * 
 */

    $valores_fa  = array( 7, 19, 25, 12, 23, 15, 8, 16 );

    $valores_faa = calculaFAAs( $valores_fa );
    $valores_fr  = calculaFRs( $valores_fa );
    $valores_fra = calculaFRAs( $valores_fr );

    $total_fa    = array_sum( $valores_fa );
    $total_faa   = array_sum( $valores_faa );
    $total_fr    = array_sum( $valores_fr );
    $total_fra   = array_sum( $valores_fra );

    /*echo '<pre>';
    var_dump( $valores_fr );
    echo '</pre>';
    die(); /**/
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Tabla</title>

        <style type="text/css">

            #verde{
                background: green;
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
            }

            table{
              border-collapse:collapse;
              background-color: #97BB00;
              border-color: white;
              text-align: center;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table  border="solid" align="center" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
<?php
    echoVerde( 'X1' );
    echoVerde( 'Frecuencia<br> absoluta' );
    echoVerde( 'Frecuencia<br> absoluta <br>acumulada' );
    echoVerde( 'Frecuencia<br>relativa' );
    echoVerde( 'Frecuencia<br>Relativa<br>acumulada' );

    //Fin primera fila
?>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
<?php 

    //Mostrando datos

    //Imprime filas con los tados
    $indice = 1;
    foreach ( $valores_fa as $key => $fa ) {

        echoValue( $indice, TRUE );
        echoValue( $fa );
        echoValue( $valores_faa[ $key ]);
        echoValue( $valores_fr[ $key ]);
        echoValue( $valores_fra[ $key ]);

        echo '</tr>';
        echo '<tr>';

        $indice++;
    }

    //Imprime fila con los totales
    echoVerde( 'TOTAL' );
    echoVerde( $total_fa );
    echoVerde( $total_faa );
    echoVerde( $total_fr );
    echoVerde( $total_fra );

?>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: De nada. No te olvides de utilizar el sistema de votaciones para valorar las respuestas que consideres interesantes. Un saludo.